# Can a S trap be converted to a P trap by adding a horizontal pipe in the "S"?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

Does adding a horizontal pipe, say 6in, in between the two S elbows convert a S-trap into a P-trap? Is it code?

See picture

[image: S-trap to P-trap]

Comment: Oh for Pete's sake. Now I have to be careful about VtC on plumbing, too, huh. Well, in this case, I'm certain of the "it's precisely a duplicate, not just related" but I am not a fan of the "1-vote close" in general.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a vent at least two pipe diameters (4" since this is 2" pipe) away from the exit of the P-trap on the left, then it's to code.

If not, it's still an S trap.